# Rasterizing shapefile with attribute value as pixel value labels with GDAL in Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, shapefile, convert

I am new to GDAL and geom shapefiles.

I have a 3-band .img file (with other associated files) as raster images.

And also a  shapefile which includes 10000+ features (multi-polygons), the properties of each includes 'shape_leng', and 'BM' (corresponding to the geographic class of this area, e.g. water/forest).

[image]

I want to rasterize the shapefile with property 'BM' as labeled pixel value (single/three channels) to put it together with my raster image so that I can visualize the segmentation or further train an image segmentation network using this as a training dataset.

How to implement it using Python? Or is there any tutorial/notebook that I can learn from?

Comment: It's quite simple to do in pure GDAL. [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/377751/2948) has a function for it using just GDAL.

Answer (score 0):

Rasterizing with GDAL *is* possible, but rather verbose in Python. The [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html) is not very explanatory. There is [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212795/rasterizing-shapefiles-with-gdal-and-python) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220749/rasterizing-a-gdal-layer) on how to do this in GDAL. However, I recommend using GeoCube [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380694/converting-shapefile-to-raster-by-passing-specific-column-variable-using-gdal-in/380699#380699), which makes it easy as Py:

```
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
import rioxarray
import geopandas as gpd

raster_path = 'your path'
vector_path = 'other path'

source_ds = gpd.read_file(vector_path)
raster = rioxarray.open_rasterio(raster_path,masked=True)
Cube = make_geocube(vector_data=source_ds['BM'],like=raster)

Cube.BM.plot()
```

good luck!